# Jolt - How to compare two values for if else condition

Tags: json, apache-nifi, equality, jolt

I have to transform in Jolt on the condition that if the value in **name** and **displayName** are same, then the output should set the flag value **displayOnUI** to **true** else **false**

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Mike Ellis",
    "email": "mike@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "MikeE"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sam Perry",
    "email": "samperry@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "Sam Perry"
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Mike Ellis",
    "email": "mike@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "MikeE",
    "displayOnUi": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Sam Perry",
    "email": "samperry@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "Sam Perry",
    "displayOnUi": true
  }
]
```

I tried to transform but was not able to get correct output. Could someone please help. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out whether the comparison of the attributes forms an array(in this case only **1** element will be generated) or individual attributes(in this case only **2** elements will be generated *nested within the new object called Count* ) through use of the following transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*ame": "Cnt[&1].Count.@0"
      },
      "@": "Original" // replicate the initial JSON value
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Cnt": {
        "*": {
          "Count": "=size(@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Count": "&1",
          "*": "&1.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "1": { // stands for the second component to compare
          "1": { // keep the values are equal
            "@(2,[0])": "[&3]",
            "#true": "[&3].displayOnUi"
          },
          "2": { // keep the values are UNequal
            "@(2,[0])": "[&3]",
            "#false": "[&3].displayOnUi"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: yes sure. Done it.